# Simple MongoDB question (amateur) about $regex

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query

query = {"Description": {“$regex” : “house”}}

I've searched online, but the explanations are weirdly complex as to what $regex does. If I ran a command like this, can you explain what the result would be and why?

Thank you!!

Comment: You can see some usage examples using [$regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) in MongoDB Manual. For general regex usage there are quite a few online tutorials, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This will return all documents from the Collection that have string `house` in its `Description` field.

Here is the working example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/ako_T8plPSw